# How to load customer with eav attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, eav-attributes

How to load a customer with an eav attribute ?

I created a new eav attribute with that :

```
$attribute  = array(
        'type'          => 'varchar',
        'input'         => 'text',
        'label'         => 'My Field',
        'global'        => true,
        'visible'       => true,
        'default'       => '',
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => 0,
        'used_in_forms' => array(
                'adminhtml_customer',
        ),
);
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'my_field', $attribute);
```

And now, I want to load customer, but the following code doesn't work :

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->load($myField, 'my_field');
```

But if I load the customer with email (for example), after, I can get 'my_field' value with :

```
$customer->getData('my_field');
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try to use This

```
$result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('my_field')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('my_field',$myFieldValue)->load();

if (is_object($result)) {
    /* Logic */
}
```